# Успокойте меня

Tags: грамотная-речь

Поспокойнее - это же нормальное слово? Как и получше, помягче и т.д.? Ворд их подчеркивает, говорит, что просторечные. Но насколько? Я совершенно этого не чувствую. Допустим, слово "нету" у меня чётко ощущается как разговорное, я его и не пишу, и практически не произношу. А "потише" запросто. А у вас? Скажем, где такая форма сравнительной степени не будет воспринята вами как неграмотность? В блоге нормально? А в газетной статье уже нет? В новостях по тв?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просторечные - вряд ли. Скорее разговорные. В научном тексте и в официальных новостях я бы подобные слова без особой нужды не использовал. В остальных случаях - вполне возможно.

Что касается блога, то по факту там вообще пишут так, как считает нужным хозяин.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение!

Answer (score 4):

Почему бы и не использовать в статьях, если это не официальный текст?) Как раз такими словами будет подчеркнута промежуточная степень-чего практически не добиться сухим официальным языком)))

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня успокоили:)

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, по-моему, слово "поспокойнее" безболезненно можно заменить на "спокойнее". И звучит менее громоздко.

Comment: Допустим. А вот с такими сочетаниями как "найти что-то получше" или "будь с ним помягче" что предлагаете делать?

Comment: Так и тут вполне можно обойтись без приставки.

Comment: Я бы не сказала, что это полностью равноценная замена. С "лучше" получается какое-то незаконченное предложение. Хочется поставить запятую и написать "чем...", иначе непонятно.
"Это нам не подходит, придется найти что-то получше". - нормальное законченное предложение.
"Это нам не подходит, придется найти что-то лучше". -??? всё равно требуется пояснение: ..., чем надувной матрас в качестве плавательного средства, к примеру.